# ftp_login failing on the second login attempt?

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to download a large number of files via FTP.  This leads to a strange Warning of

`Warning: ftp_get(): Getting data connection.`

My solution was just to log out, using ftp_close, and log back in, code is shown below, however, this leads to the warning of

`Warning: ftp_login(): User name okay, need password`

The thing is I am using the exact same user name and password when I get the previous warning and I have already downloaded dozens of files by this point so the user name and password are correct.  I also have the code print the credentials just to confirm that they are the correct ones and that they exist.  Has anyone else dealt with this kind of warning combination?

The code I use to login.

```
        //Attempt to connect and login to the server
        if (!$this->oFTP = ftp_connect($this->cHost)) {
            exit("\n<br>COULD NOT CONNECT TO SERVER: $this->cHost");
        } else {
            echo "\n<br>CONNECTION SUCESSFUL: $this->cHost";
            if(!ftp_login($this->oFTP, $this->cFtpUserName, $this->cFtpUserPass)){
                exit("\n<br>LOGIN FAILURE!: $this->cFtpUserName, $this->cFtpUserPass");
            } else {
                echo "\n<br>LOGIN SUCESSFUL: $this->cFtpUserName";
            }
        }

        //Make sure we are using the correct ip address
        ftp_set_option($this->oFTP, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);

        //Allows us to retrive files
        ftp_pasv($this->oFTP,true);
```

EDIT:

After some asked about this I looked back of my logs of the connection and it looks like this might not actually be getting any files with ftp_get.  I have another script that runs the exact same function with the same login credentials so I know it is working.  If that were running at the same time could that be an issue?

Comment: Does anything work after the `ftp_put`? Did you try something simple, like `ftp_size`? + *"and log back in"* - do you just login using `ftp_login`? Or do you reconnect as well using `ftp_connect`? + Are you able to capture the communication between PHP and the server (e.g. using Wireshark)? Or do you have an access to FTP server log file? + Are you able to upload multiple files using any FTP client connected to the same server? Can you show us its log file?

Comment: I run the function I showed in my question again.  I run the ftp_connect and I get a successful connection.  It displays the warning at ftp_login in this function.  Can I run other functions if I have not logged in?  I don't have any way to get the communication easily.  Do you know of any functions that can print this information while the code is running?

Comment: I was asking if `ftp_size` works after the `ftp_put` in the *first* connection. + PHP FTP module does not provide any logs. That's why I've asked for another logs. + You didn't answer all of my questions.

Comment: It is a ftp_get not put.  Also, looking over the log that I make it seems that the get might not be working.  However, I have another script that runs the same function and works fine with this server.  If it were running at the same time, with the same credentials, could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes it could, if the server limits number of concurrent connections. You need to talk to the server administrator.

Comment: Alright, I changed when that function runs so they shouldn't overlap. I will update tomorrow when the code runs and if it works you can add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Got the function to run today with no issues.  Looks like the issue was the dual login.  If you want you can post that as an answer and I will accept.  If not I will just put that as the answer.

Comment: If your server does not allow concurrent login, then you do not have a programming question in the first place. That's something you should have tested by an FTP client beforehand.